# Oauth : can json have oauth token?

Tags: oauth

I am simulating an app where json requests are sent at the back. Now i have to add oauth support. I don't know how to move forward. Is the oauth token sent with the same json request?

Comment: I think we need more information to help you.  It depends on the api reall how the information is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.. an oauth token is sent in the HTTP headers. So, ti's not in the json payload, but it is sent in the same HTTP request.

HOwever, before sending it, you have to accomplish some steps dictated by the standard, to exchange the proper token(s) (access and/or request)

Look at this good tutorial http://hueniverse.com/oauth/guide/ to understand the process more in depth. It even has an interactive part where you can dynamically change the parameters and see the headers and messages you should generate and exchange.